# Backup iPhone to Mac Via Terminal Command

Tags: macos, terminal, backup

Does anyone know what the Terminal command is in macOS to trigger an iPhone or iPad backup through finder? I need both and I'd like to have them run at certain times of the day automatically. Thanks!

Comment: @RyderCragie see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/370531/catalina-backup-ios-devices-programatically